# ¿Error no encontrado al ejecutar un servicio en php con wamp?

Tags: php, mysql, angular, slim

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

He creado servicios en php  para usarlo en angular y lo estoy ejecutando con wamp pero me sale un error y dice lo siguiente.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a http://localhost/curso-angular4-backend/index.php/productos status of 404 (Not Found)
```

pero cuando le doy clic a la ruta me sale una pagina diciendo  ***Not Found***, y si le agrego al localhost:8080 si me muestra el json con datos. Y pienso que el problema es el localhost que no aparece con el puerto 8080, agradecería me pudieran ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que tienes uno en el puerto 80 y otro en el 8080, ¿tienes dos servidores corriendo al mismo tiempo? ¿Cómo llamas al servicio?

Comment: De acuerdo tienes razón lo estaba llamando con otro puerto.